# Selecting objects in a collection

Tags: collections

I was trying to select the objects in the newly create collection but i was not able to select as newbie i don't know some rookie mistake there so kindly help me with this[I have attached the video kindly check on it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1afkKMfyb-r0RHovY0GG_81ooaQEyW1EA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why are you switching to Scenes in the Outliner?  - Once you moved the cubes to the new collection you could select them individually and work on them as usual without switching to the Scene view! In any case you could have just clicked on 'Objects' in the Outliner and selected them from there.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Not sure why it's not possible to select them when you are in Scenes display mode

Comment: @moonboots You can select them if you expand the Objects section in the Scene outliner. I assume the Scene Collection entry there just includes the names of the collections which you can rename and enable/disable.

Comment: Sure but I agree with you, I'm not sure why he switch to Scene

Comment: okay sure i will use in built to upload gifs or images without using external links.So can any one tell me how should i  select the objects in a collection .I saw a video where they created a collection with some objects and when they selected the collection in the scenes all the objects in the collection were selected so i was  trying to do the same thing.So image imagine i want to add all black and white chess pieces to two different collection and i want to select the black color pieces alone may i know what to do.